# Can I give the text and line elements that make up a D3 axis unique classes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In D3, when creating axes, is it possible to assign a class to each line and text element in a g.tick?

I'm looking to end up with an axis rendered like this:

```
<g class="yAxis" style="transform: translate(617px, 2em);">
    <g class="tick" style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,0)">
     <line class="foo" x2="-555" y2="0">
     <text class="foo" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: start;" x="3" y="0">2012</text>
    </g>
   <g class="tick" style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,21.64860000000002)">
    <line class="bar" x2="-555" y2="0">
    <text class="bar" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: start;" x="3" y="0">2013</text>
   </g>
</g>
```

I see that I can select the SVG, append a g element and call the yAxis. How would I generate classes for the line/text elements within them?

```
var yTickLabels = ["2012","2013"];

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("right")  
    .ticks(25)
    .tickSize(-width * 0.5)
    .tickFormat(function(d,i){
      return yTickLabels[i];
});

svg
 .append("g")
 .attr({
    "class" : "yAxis"
  })
  .style({
    "transform" : function () {
      return "translate(" + ((width/2) + 62) + "px,2em)";
    }
  })
  .call(yAxis);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement by:

```
var yAxis = svg.append('g')
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);

yAxis.selectAll("text")  
 .attr("class", "axis-text");

yAxis.selectAll("line")  
 .attr("class", "axis-line");
```

However, you can style axis line/text directly instead of via classes, such as:

```
var yAxis = svg.append('g')
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis)
.selectAll("text")  
 .attr("y", 3)
 .attr("x", -10)
```